# Is it possible to override the camera in JS?

Tags: javascript, qr-code, getusermedia, mediastream

I'm working with a big company, and part of their flow is scanning a QR code to register some data. The problem is, in order to test this, I need to generate a QR code from the data, photograph it on my phone, and scan it in through my laptop's camera.

There are NPM modules for creating QR codes from data so that's okay, but I was wondering if it's somehow possible to override getUserMedia to return a stream of bytes that is just a QR code? I was thinking of maybe encapsulating all this into one nice chrome extension, but from looking around online, I'm not sure how I'd 'override' the camera input and replace it with a stream of QR code bytes instead.

Thanks

Comment: Why not skip the QR business and send the actual data as stream?

Comment: The logic to grab that QR code should be in a separate function/module so you can replace it with something else if necessary - like a stub in this case

Comment: Fully agreed, but this is a big and ancient codebase and it takes ages to get any sort of change pushed through. The joys of being a contractor...

Answer (score 2):

The HTMLCanvasElement has a [`captureStream()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream) method that does produce a MediaStream with a VideoTrack similar to what `getUserMedia({video: true})` produces.
This is a convenient way to test various things with a video stream, without needing an human in the loop:

```js
const width = 1280;
const height = 720
const canvas = Object.assign(document.createElement("canvas"), {width, height});
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
// you'd do the drawing you wish, here I prepare some noise
const img = new ImageData(width, height);
const data = new Uint32Array(img.data.buffer);
const anim = () => {
  for(let i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
    data[i] = 0xFF000000 + Math.random()*0xFFFFFF;
  }
  ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
};
requestAnimationFrame(anim);
// extract the MediaStream from the canvas
const stream = canvas.captureStream();
// Use it in your test (here I'll just display it in the <video>)
document.querySelector("video").srcObject = stream;
```

```css
video { height: 100vh }
```

```html
<video controls autoplay></video>
```

But in your case, you need to separate the concerns.
The QR code detection tests should be done on their own, and these can certainly use still images instead of a MediaStream.